# Using %in% in ifelse statements?

Tags: r

I know there are many questions on ifelse statements on the forum already, but I cannot seem to find an answer to my particular query.

I would like to use ifelse to generate a new column in a dataframe based on either of two conditions. Basically I want hypertension to say 1 if "hypertension" is in the heart conditions column, OR, if bp medication=1. As you can see below the hypertension column is marked as 1 for all rows currently.
Is there an issue with using the %in% command in an ifelse statement, or have I gone wrong somewhere else along the way?

```
heart_conditions                  high_chol_tabs            bp_med         hypertension
                                            
 1 hypertension high_cholesterol 2 [no]              2 [no]                        1
 2 none                          4 [not applicable]  4 [not applicable]            1
 3 hypertension high_cholesterol 1 [yes]             1 [yes]                       1
 4 heart_attack angina           4 [not applicable]  4 [not applicable]            1
 5 high_cholesterol              2 [no]              4 [not applicable]            1
 6 hypertension high_cholesterol 1 [yes]             1 [yes]                       1
 7 none                          4 [not applicable]  4 [not applicable]            1
 8 none                          4 [not applicable]  4 [not applicable]            1
 9 high_cholesterol              2 [no]              4 [not applicable]            1
10 hypertension high_cholesterol 1 [yes]             1 [yes]                       1
```

```
hypertension.df$hypertension <- ifelse(("hypertension" %in% heart_conditions)|(bp_med == 1), 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it the wrong way around. What you want is `heart_conditions %in% "hypertension"` (or `heart_conditions == "hyptertension"`)!

Or the full answer:

```
hypertension.df$hypertension <- ifelse(heart_conditions == "hypertension" | bp_med == 1, 1, 2)

# or using %in%
selection <- "hypertension"
hypertension.df$hypertension <- ifelse(heart_conditions %in% selection | bp_med == 1, 1, 2)
```

## Longer Explanation

`%in%` checks if the left-hand-side is present in the right-hand-side and returns an object of the length of the left-hand-side.

```r
names <- c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie")

names %in% c("Alice", "Charlie")
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
"Alice" %in% names
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

## Partial Matches

As mentioned in the comments: `%in%` fully compares the elements. To check if a string is inside another string, we can do the following:

### String Comparison

```r
library(tibble) # data.frames

df <- tribble(
  ~heart_conditions, ~high_chol_tabs, ~bp_med, ~hypertension,
  "hypertension high_cholesterol", 2, 2, 1,
  "none", 4, 4, 1,
  "hypertension high_cholesterol", 1, 1, 1,
  "heart_attack angina", 4, 4, 1,
  "high_cholesterol", 2, 4, 1,
  "hypertension high_cholesterol", 1, 1, 1,
  "none", 4, 4, 1,
  "none", 4, 4, 1,
  "high_cholesterol", 2, 4, 1,
  "hypertension high_cholesterol", 1, 1, 1
)



df$hypertension1 <- ifelse(grepl("hypertension", df$heart_conditions) | df$bp_med == 1, 1, 2)

library(stringr)

# imho more user friendly than grepl, but slightly slower
df$hypertension2 <- ifelse(str_detect(df$heart_conditions, "hypertension") | df$bp_med == 1, 1, 2)

df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#>    heart_conditions high_chol_tabs bp_med hypertension hypertension1
#>    <chr>                     <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1 hypertension hi…              2      2            1             1
#>  2 none                          4      4            1             2
#>  3 hypertension hi…              1      1            1             1
#>  4 heart_attack an…              4      4            1             2
#>  5 high_cholesterol              2      4            1             2
#>  6 hypertension hi…              1      1            1             1
#>  7 none                          4      4            1             2
#>  8 none                          4      4            1             2
#>  9 high_cholesterol              2      4            1             2
#> 10 hypertension hi…              1      1            1             1
#> # … with 1 more variable: hypertension2 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

### Split and Compare

A slightly slower solution, which does not rely on string comparison, is to split the conditions by space and check if any are hypertension, you can do it like so:

```r
# split the heart-conditions
conds <- strsplit(df$heart_conditions, " ")
conds
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "hypertension"     "high_cholesterol"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "none"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "hypertension"     "high_cholesterol"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "heart_attack" "angina"      
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "high_cholesterol"
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] "hypertension"     "high_cholesterol"
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] "none"
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] "none"
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] "high_cholesterol"
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1] "hypertension"     "high_cholesterol"
# for each row of the data, check if any value is hypertension
has_hypertension <- sapply(conds, function(cc) any(cc == "hypertension"))
has_hypertension
#>  [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

df$hypertension3 <- ifelse(has_hypertension | df$bp_med == 1, 1, 2)
df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 7
#>    heart_conditions high_chol_tabs bp_med hypertension hypertension1
#>    <chr>                     <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1 hypertension hi…              2      2            1             1
#>  2 none                          4      4            1             2
#>  3 hypertension hi…              1      1            1             1
#>  4 heart_attack an…              4      4            1             2
#>  5 high_cholesterol              2      4            1             2
#>  6 hypertension hi…              1      1            1             1
#>  7 none                          4      4            1             2
#>  8 none                          4      4            1             2
#>  9 high_cholesterol              2      4            1             2
#> 10 hypertension hi…              1      1            1             1
#> # … with 2 more variables: hypertension2 <dbl>, hypertension3 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

## Benchmark

Intrigued by my earlier comments, I ran a quick benchmark comparing the different solutions, also adding a solution using `stringi`:

```r
# splitter function
has_hypertension <- function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(cc) any(cc == "hypertension"))

# create a larger dataset
df_large <- df %>% slice(rep(1:n(), 10000))

# benchmark the code:
bench::mark(
  grepl = grepl("hypertension", df_large$heart_conditions),
  stringi = stringi::stri_detect(df_large$heart_conditions, fixed = "hypertension"),
  stringr = str_detect(df_large$heart_conditions, "hypertension"),
  splitter = has_hypertension(df_large$heart_conditions)
)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 13
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result        memory               time        gc            
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   #> <bch:tm> <list>        <list>               <list>      <list>        
#> 1 grepl       16.67ms  16.91ms     59.0   390.67KB     2.11    28     1      474ms <lgl [100,00… <Rprofmem[,3] [1 × … <bch:tm [2… <tibble [29 ×…
#> 2 stringi      2.68ms   2.93ms    344.    390.67KB     6.22   166     3      482ms <lgl [100,00… <Rprofmem[,3] [1 × … <bch:tm [1… <tibble [169 …
#> 3 stringr     17.74ms  17.96ms     55.1   390.67KB     0       28     0      508ms <lgl [100,00… <Rprofmem[,3] [1 × … <bch:tm [2… <tibble [28 ×…
#> 4 splitter   153.39ms 153.39ms      6.52    3.67MB    19.6      1     3      153ms <lgl [100,00… <Rprofmem[,3] [551 … <bch:tm [4… <tibble [4 × …
```

Which clearly shows that `stringi::stri_detect(txt, fixed = "hypertension")` is by far the fastest!

Comment: Thanks David. That seems to have mostly worked, unfortunately it has not in a few cases, for example in the row below. So although it says hypertension in the heart conditions column it stills comes up as 2? This seems to be happening in rows that have more than 2 heart conditions listed. Is there a way to fix this?

`(
 heart_conditions                           high_chol_tabs             bp_med       hypertension

1 hypertension high_cholesterol    2 [no]                     2 [no]                        2
)`

Comment: `%in%` checks element wise (that is it compares the values fully, i.e., is `"hypertension high_cholesterol"` equal to `"hypertension"` => No). Ill add some options to the answer!

Comment: Thank you so much David, you are an absolute legend! It worked perfectly. As an absolute novice in R having people as patient and generous with their time as you, has really helped me along!

Comment: Always a pleasure of helping people getting into R :) You may want to have a look at the tidyverse (dplyr in this case) or data.table as they allow for much nicer data.frame manipulations!

Comment: Thanks again David, I'll definitely look into those!

Comment: Just as a follow up, could I do something like this, to capture other heart conditions?
(`has_other_heart_con <- sapply(conds, function(cc) any(cc == "angina", "heart_attack", "stroke"))

MCR_PA_Data_Analysis$other_heart_con <- ifelse(has_other_heart_con, 1, 2) `)

Comment: Not quite, replace the contents of `any()` with `cc %in% selection` and set to `selection <- c("angina", "heart_attack", "stroke")`. See my updates on speed, the string comparisons are faster, to include multiple cases use the regex `angina|heart_attack|stroke`.